# full path as the filename

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-pipelines

Maybe someone knows a simple solution to my problem. 
I do not know the entry of the file so it's not a static value. 
It can be changed through the BizTalk gui and there we have a URI through the receiveport. But I do not believe it's accessible that easy. What I want to do is write out the full path as the filename. It works well with the messageID where the file is given a specific filepath name. But the Path-Name where the file was dropped is not working that well.
I keep getting this error :

Message:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table
-Does not say me much

Below you can see a snip from my code

```
internal static string UpdateMacroPathProperty(IBaseMessage baseMessage, string macroPathProperty, string macroDefsFile)
{
   if (macroName == "MessageID")
   {
      contextPropertyValue = baseMessage.MessageID.ToString();
   }
   else if (macroName == "SourceFileName")
   {               
      contextPropertyValue = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
   }
}
```

This is an specific created pipeline. Has anyone encountered this problem or can point me in the right way.

I know that BizTalk has a built in function for this, [BizTalk Server: List of Macros](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8823.biztalk-server-list-of-macros.aspx) as the `%SourceFileName%` but I'm trying to save this as logs in a specific map structure so that it does not get processed.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

It's adapter dependent; some adapters will use the `FILE` adapter's namespace even though they're not the file adapter, but this is the kind of logic that I've used in the past for this:

```csharp
string adapterType = (string)pInMsg.Context.Read("InboundTransportType",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties");
string filePath = null;

if (adapterType != null)
{
    if (adapterType == "FILE")
    {
        filePath = (string)pInMsg.Context.Read("ReceivedFileName",
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/file-properties");
    }
    else if (adapterType.Contians("SFTP") && !adapterType.Contains("nsoftware")) 
    // nsoftware uses the FTP schema
    {
        filePath = (string)pInMsg.Context.Read("ReceivedFileName",
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2012/Adapter/sftp-properties");
    }
    else if (adapterType.Contains("FTP"))
    {
        filePath = (string)pInMsg.Context.Read("ReceivedFileName",
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/ftp-properties");
    }
}
```

And then you can just fall back to the `MessageID` if you can't get the file path from any of these.